# Jquery onclick this remove both of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

how to do that when i Click to "OnClick" will remove City1 and City2 
I mean want to remove both of them by one click.
Waiting for your reply 
thanks.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" >
<option value="First" >First</option>
<option value="Second" >Second</option>
<option value="Third" >Third</option>
</select>
<div id="City1"  ></div>
<div id="City2"  ></div>

  $(document).ready(function()
{
 var i = 0;

    $("#city").click(function(){
        var sel=$(this).val();  

         i++;

        $('#City1, #City2').append('<span id="'+ [i] +'"style="border-radius:5px;color:#fff;background-color:#005e3a;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:auto;" onclick="$(this).remove();">'+ sel +'</span>');


});

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeynaloffnet/WRs86/2/

Comment: What do you want to click to remove them both?

Comment: i want to click to added SPAN for remove both of added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've got your answer already, but I thought it might be worth pointing out a few things.

When creating DOM elements, you might consider using the object literal syntax, where you create the element as usual, then add its properties using key/value pairs:

```
$('<div'>, { class: 'myDiv'});
```

Ids cannot start with a number. It might be worth appending the option's value to a prefix instead:

```
id: "opt-" + this.value,
```

It's a good idea to give your new span a specific class , then alter its appearance by targeting it from a separate style-sheet. This will remove the need for all that ugly and hard to maintain, inline CSS.

These changes would give you something like:

```
span {
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#005e3a;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:auto;
}

<select multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>

$("#mySelect").click(function () {
    var span = $("<span />", {
        id: "opt-" + this.value.toLowerCase(),
        class: "city",
        text: this.value,
        click: function () {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    $('#result').html(span);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/LC2z2/)

**EDIT**:

Here's how you'd do it with two elements:

```
$("#mySelect").click(function () {
    var span1 = $("<span />", {
        class: "opt-" + this.value.toLowerCase(),
        text: this.value,
        click: function () {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }),
    span2 = span.clone(true);

    $('#result').empty().append(span1).append(span2);
});
```

You have to clone the original span, as append actually moves the element, so appending it twice wouldn't work.

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/LC2z2/1/)

I also changed the `id` attribute to `class`, as ids should be unique to a page.

Comment: Thanks! it's excellent. But one thing when i click it appears just one  result but i need when i click to result have 2 the same thing and when i want to remove they have to removed together,for same.

Comment: how to remove clone? :D

Comment: Ah, sorry! When you clone the element, pass it the argument of `true`, so that event handlers are cloned as well: `span2 = span.clone(true);`. I updated my answer. Here's a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/LC2z2/2/).

Comment: but not removed together for same :(

Comment: You want both spans removed when you click on either one?

Comment: I want both spans removed click on either one. same value

Comment: Alter the event handler like this: click: `function (){ $("#result").empty(); }` [New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/LC2z2/3/)

Comment: $('#result').empty().append(span);  that does not allow more select.$('#result').append(span);  on clicked, all them removed

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry. Did you not try my fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zeynaloffnet/q998B/1/  $('#result').empty().append(span); that does not allow more select.$('#result').append(span); on clicked, all them removed

Comment: Change your event handler to this: click: `function (){ $("." + this.className).remove(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clean the div before. Use .empty() before .append()

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" >
<option value="First" >First</option>
<option value="Second" >Second</option>
<option value="Third" >Third</option>
</select>
<div id="City1"  ></div>
<div id="City2"  ></div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i = 0;
    $("#city").click(function(){
        var sel=$(this).val();
        i++;
        $('#City1, #City2').empty().append('<span id="'+ [i] +'"style="border-radius:5px;color:#fff;background-color:#005e3a;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:auto;" onclick="$(this).remove();">'+ sel +'</span>');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/WRs86/3/

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/WRs86/9/)

If you want to replace the contents..simply change `append` to `html`

```
       $('#City1, #City2').html('<span id="' + [i] + '"style="border-radius:5px;color:#fff;background-color:#005e3a;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:auto;">' + sel + '</span>');
```

To remove both `span` elements when only clicking one or the other, take the `onclick` function out and replace with

```
       $('#City1 span, #City2 span').on('click',function () {
           $('#City1 span, #City2 span').remove();
       });
```

Comment: I don't need HTML, i need APPEND for choose more select. but when clicked want to remove both of which the same

Comment: @user3592444 - OK great, in that case the second bit of code is all you need :)

Comment: when i choose multiple i want them to be different. but this do it in same SPAN ))

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="removeCity();"//add this as your onlick

var removeCity = function()
{
$("#City1").remove();
$("#City2").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understaning, Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kailashyadav/WRs86/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var i = 0;

       $("#city").click(function () {
           var sel = $(this).val();

           i++;

           $('#City1, #City2').append('<span class="spanClass" id="' + [i] + '"style="border-radius:5px;color:#fff;background-color:#005e3a;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:auto;" onclick="$(\'.spanClass\').remove();">' + sel + '</span>');


       });

   });
```